Installer crashes after selecting Korean Language
I have an installer that is translated into many languages. They are displayed in the standard Droplist in their own language and it works good.
I wanted to change the Droplist to a ListBox, or a TreeView. That works as well, but when I now select the Korean language (only there!), the installer keeps starting up the language selection dialog again.
I tried multiple different types of lists/boxes but it's always the same with the Korean language.
I edit the MultiLanguage.ini with InstallOptionsEX in a custom pre function:
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE lang_pre
and change the list type like this:
WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\MultiLanguage.ini" "Field 4" "Type" "TreeView"
WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\MultiLanguage.ini" "Field 4" "Notify" "ONDBLCLICK"

Another weird thing is that if I don't change the Droplist, I can move it anywhere with
WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\MultiLanguage.ini" "Field 4" "Left" "70"
WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\MultiLanguage.ini" "Field 4" "Top" "135"

but no matter how I set the Bottom value, e.g. 170, the Droplist is way too long and goes beyond the programs borders.
I use NSIS 3.05 with UMUI 2.0 b6 and InstallOptionsEx 2.4.5 b3.

Add example code please...

Sorry @anders added code now

You cannot prevent a combobox (droplist) from expanding outside the parent window. It also does not respect the height you give it. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060310-17/?p=31973

I don't know anything about UMUI and InstallOptionsEx, sorry.

oh okay, still thank you for that link
